# How to upgrade Tensorflow to v1.3 (cuDNN & CUDA upgrade)

Tags: cuda

First, below is my system environment

1. OS: Ubuntu 16.04
2. current tensorflow: 1.0.1
3. current cuDNN: 5.1.5
4. current CUDA: 8.0

I want to upgrade tensorflow to 1.3, but tf 1.3 requires cuDNN 6.

So upgrading cuDNN is necessary but I can't find the way how to *upgrade* cuDNN and *configure* tensorflow as I installed before.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a script that can be used to clean install a desired version of cuDNN or upgrade an existing one. Once you perform the steps on the GitHub page, you can change your cuDNN version to v6.0. After that, you don't have to make any configuration for TensorFlow, it will start working automatically with cuDNN v6.0. You can find the script [here](https://github.com/dnzzcn/cuDNNv).

This is what the script does:

```
#!/bin/bash

rm -f /usr/include/cudnn.h
rm -f /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/*libcudnn*
rm -f /usr/local/cuda-*/lib64/*libcudnn*


cp -P packages/cudnn/include/cudnn.h /usr/include
cp -P packages/cudnn/lib64/libcudnn* /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
chmod a+r /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcudnn*

rm -rf packages/cudnn
```

It performs installing operations automatically for the version you want.

Comment: Hi dnzzcn, please include your script to the answer, link only answers are unwelcome.